# ¿Existe un límite de trabajo en R con matrices con filas mayores a las 50 mil?

Tags: c++, r

Estoy replicando la correlación de `spearman` en `R`, en conjunto con el `Rcpp` para usar las funciones de `C++`, pero tengo un error consistente:

Cada vez que tomo matrices con filas mayores a las (alrededor) de 45 - 50 mil, mi correlación (delimitada teóricamente entre -1 y 1) se distorsiona terriblemente y puede ir tanto para cifras menores a -1 como mayores a 1. 
He corroborado que cada vez que uso matrices con filas menores al umbral que les comento, todo va bien. Supongo debe haber algún límite de trabajo en mi computadora (16 GB de RAM), ya que no encuentro otra explicación.

Solo para comentarles, una matriz de 60 000 filas, la recorto a 45 000 y el resultado de mi función `Rcpp` cae dentro del rango normal de una correlación. Le permito trabajar con todas sus files y termina siendo -18.

Si alguien tuviera algún comentario le agradecería muchísimo.

Comment: Por curiosidad, ¿puedes reproducir los mismos cálculos con otra herramienta (un Excel, por ejemplo)? Y llegar a determinar alrededor de qué número de fila los resultados comienzan a divergir?

Comment: Esta pregunta tiene una respuesta en inglés aquí: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38757326/is-there-a-limit-on-working-with-matrix-in-r-with-rcpp

Comment: seria bueno que le traduzcan o pongan parte de la respuesta traducida para los que a futuro tengan este problema

Answer (score 0):

Solucion:

Utilizar una implementacion de 64bits o un workaround de la matriz, que soporte mas elementos.

Te sobrepasas de cantidad de elementos que una matriz puede contener al llegar a ese valor que superas. Depende de el tamaño de entero que este soportando tu maquina, arquitectura, libreria que utilices. Claramente es de 32bit tu aplicacion y por eso falla con ese numero. Si consigues una implementacion de 64bit puedes tener muchos mas elementos.

Puedes crear una clase matriz que maneje los elementos de forma apropiada cuando llega a los valores de peligro. Perderas performance pero funcionara.